# scrollViewWillEndDragging targetContentOffset.memory not changed in Xcode 6 beta 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollviewdelegate, xcode6

Here I have following code, trying to change the value of targetContentOffset, however I only got the println() working, view still not changed after I set offset

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafePointer<CGPoint>) {

    println( "got something" )
    targetContentOffset.memory.x = 200
    targetContentOffset.memory.y = 200
}
```

update:

I am able to scroll the view automatically when I did following. However when I set **animated** to **true** it doesn't work.

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.memory = CGPointMake( CGFloat( 156.0 ) , CGFloat( 0.0 ) )
    scrollView.setContentOffset( CGPointMake( CGFloat( 156.0 ) , CGFloat( 0.0 ) ), animated: false )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted cell from my storyboard, and rewrote everything in code. Somehow it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be calling `scrollView.setContentOffset` inside of `scrollViewWillEndDragging`. `scrollViewWillEndDragging` is called automatically when user scrolling has stopped, and it gives you the opportunity to modify the `targetContentOffset` accordingly.

This should animate the scrollView's `contentOffset` to the modified `targetContentOffset` automatically:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.memory = CGPointMake(CGFloat(156.0), CGFloat(0.0))
}
```